# Do you validate login form before forwarding to j_spring_security_check?

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-security

Option 1: Set form's action to j_spring_security_check and let spring handle it
Option 2: Validate the login form inside the controller and then forward to j_spring_security_check
Which one is the best practice? I guess option 2 but maybe there is no need to do that so that's why I ask.
Oh, and I'm talking about server side validation, no javascript here.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I wanted to do was to validate the login form (for special signs only that are not allowed) 
but I ended up just letting spring security handle it.
Thanks for your suggestions though.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to validate it? Its not very common to give any information about your underlying system on login form - user either passed correct data or not. I would consider showing any more info than "Password or login incorrect" insecure ( like "Wrong password" - so anyone knows that user with specified login exists in your system ).

Comment: Well, I don't want to show more info. It's obvious that it's insecure. I was just thinking about something like special signs validation. For example, if username contains some weird characters, instantly respond that its incorrect. I was just curious if it's not faster since spring security must search the database.